# i want to print "hello!!!!!" from home.html in django but it says TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django

i want to print "hello!!!!!" from home.html in django but it says TemplateDoesNotExist.
code of all the pages

```
home.html

<h1>hello!!!!!!!!!</h1>


urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home , name='home')
]


views.py

from django.http import request
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(requests):
    return render(request , 'home.html')


setting.py

DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
```

Comment: Where is your template located, please share the file structure.

Comment: templates folder under project folder

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this error occur when you forgot to add app name in your `setting.py` file `INSTALLED_APPs` list or you have wrong file path.

For `installed_apps`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....,
    Your_app_name,
]
```

For templates structure

```
templates
-----index.html
```